# Random floating title in website next to gallery, (@media queries also don't work)

Tags: css, html, media-queries

Website in question: [s123c.github.io](http://s123c.github.io)

Recently I started making a one page scrolling website as a side project and used a 'selector' portfolio. I also added a auto-scroll masthead.

I came across the issue of the next title (Side Projects) after the portfolio gallery sticking to the right side. I can't understand what triggered this happening as I can remember it working swell before.

Also @media queries have stopped working which is definitely related as the inline title "Side Projects" moves down as the window gets smaller. I feel as if the @media queries no longer work and the browser is automatically using default scaling.

Any advice appreciated (but please don't advise me to get Framework or Bootstrap. I'm aware of the options).

Comment: You need to clear the floats in `#portfolio` with a clearfix. Adding `#portfolio { overflow: auto; }` is a quick way to do that

Comment: the media queries in layout.css seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the website is suppose to look but adding `display: inline-block;` to the id `#portfoliolist` is pushing that div down below all your thumbnails.

```
#portfoliolist {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but while your solution solves the line break problem the image gallery is no longer responsive and just creates a horizontal scroll when pushed in. Any solutions to this? (If not thanks for the start)